# Clase en Java con Tipo de Propiedad Dinamica

Tags: java, jackson, deserialize

Tengo el siguiente problema en java necesito crear una clase que pueda tener una propiedad que el tipo de la misma se lo pueda pasar en la definicion de la Clase. esto con la finalidad de al momento de desrealizar el objeto con jackson dentro del mismo ya este el tipo de objeto que estoy esperando. ejemplo

```
public class Response<T> {

private Instant timestamp;
private int status;
private String error;
private T body;
private String message;
private String path;
getters and setters ....
```

se usaria asi

```
Response<String> response = new ObjectMapper.readValue(body, Response<String>.class);
```

evidentemente lo anterior no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar esto:

```
Response<String> response = new ObjectMapper().readValue(body, new TypeReference<Response<String>>(){});
```

Además, tienes que importar esta clase:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
```